# how to change the color of button image on clicking?

Tags: html, css

**Here is my code**

Here i used "hover" of CSS to change the button image font color when mouse pointer is on button image...now i need to change the Image color OR font color when i click on button image...

So help me to give this requirement to my button image....

CSS code for button image :

```
        <style>
            .button {
                border: none;
                background: url('images/btn_login.jpg') no-repeat top left;
                color:white;
                padding: 2px 8px;
             }
             .button:hover {
                 border: none;
                 background: url('images/btn_login.jpg') no-repeat top left;
                 color:black;
                 padding: 2px 8px;
              }
           </style>
```

HTML code :

```
      <td width="84"><input name="login" class="button" id="" type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<td width="84"><input name="login" class="button" onclick="this.style.color = 'green';" id="id" type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following javascript code to change the color of the `button` class when clicked:

```
<td width="84"><input name="login" class="button" onclick="changeColor()" id="id" type="submit" value="Login" /></td>


<script>  
    function changeColor() {
        document.getElementById("id").style.color = "green";
    }   

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 selectors:

:active when mouse is down

:focus  when mouse is released if button keeps the focus.

Comment: this is what it does , instead  :hover use :focus. test solution pleaze.

Comment: well I believe what GCyrillus answered would work for you so you can use sth like - `.button:acive{background: url('your image')`

Comment: ya i tested them.....but it is functioning when mouse pointer is on it but i need when we try to click on it....

Comment: .button:focus => when clicked , :active => when clicking , :hover => when hovering ... i do not make the CSS rules, i only use them :) look : http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:focus

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
            .button {
                border: none;
                background: url('images/btn_login.jpg') no-repeat top left;
                color:white;
                padding: 2px 8px;
             }
             .button:hover {
                 border: none;
                 background: url('images/btn_login.jpg') no-repeat top left;
                 color:black !important;
                 padding: 2px 8px;
         background-color:#F00 !important;
              } 
           </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
            .button {
             border: none;
             background: url('images/btn_login.jpg') no-repeat top left;
             color:white;
             padding: 2px 8px;
             }
             .button:hover {
              border: none;
              background: url('images/btn_login.jpg') no-repeat top left;
              color:black;
              padding: 2px 8px;
              }
             .buttonhover {
              border: none;
              background: url('images/btn_login.jpg') no-repeat top left;
              color:black;
              padding: 2px 8px;
              }
```

Jquery:

```
$(".button").on('click',function(){
 $(this).removeClass('button');
$(this).addClass('buttonhover');
})
```

Comment: am new to jquery how can i add the above jquery code to my php file

Comment: i think this would help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347966/php-jquery-how-to-use-these-two-together-please-see-my-example