# clicking on second option jquery wont work onless i click on anything elese on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem with my Jquery. I am trying to understand why it is not working.

FOR EXAMPLE
i have a two div tags in my header that contain HOME and Products

I am trying to do internal linking with jquery to the div tags HOME and PRODUCTS

```
<body>
<div id="#header_container">

<div>
<a href="#home_content"> <span id="home_select"> HOME </span></a>
</div>

<div>
<a href="#product_content"> <span id="product_select"> PRODUCTS </span></a>
</div>

</div><!--header_content end-->

<div id="home_content"> BLABLABLABLABLABLABLA </div>
<div id="products_content"> BLABLABLABLABLABLABLA   </div>
 </body>
```

When i load the page, the first click on HOME works fine and the second click on PODUCTS works after i click on home first.

If i had to load the page and click on PRODUCTS first, it wont work. If i loaded the page and clicked on anything else on the page before clicking on PRODUCTS it will work.

Simply clicking on PRODUCTS after refreshing the page does not work, unless i click on another function on page. I am not sure why its doing this. I need some help.

my jquery code is

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($("#home_select").click(function(){$("html, body")
.animate({scrollTop:    $("#home_content").offset().top});
 }));

if ($("#product_select").click(function(){$("html, body")
.animate({scrollTop: $("#product_content").offset().top});
})); 

});
</script>
</head>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your animation to click events try this and just have href="#" in your links:

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#home_select").on("click", function(){
     $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#home_content").offset().top});

    });

   $("#product_select").on("click", function(){
      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#products_content").offset().top});
   }); 


 </script>
```

Comment: tacking out the if attribute did not change anything

Comment: I think i have an idea why its behaving wired, i have display:none on (products_content) div which is tied to another jquery function to display it as you slide down the page. how do i disable the display:none in my CSS on click, i think this might fix it.

Comment: you should have the display: none in a css file (maybe you do already). give it a class name, like hdndiv, then to show a div, you could use $("#products_content").removeClass("hdndiv") . here is a new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/565mdak9/4/

Comment: I figured it out, since i had display:none in my CSS, i just added $('#product_content').show(); and its working

Comment: Hey Cory, have you tried the Jsfiddle code in Opera and Chrome, it does not work. I just tried it and have spent some time figuring out what the problem could be. Please let me know if you know the fix to that

Comment: Please try Opera, and please let me know what .js Lib you used. I have tried Chrome and Opera and no luck, using your jsfiddle code

Comment: Hey Cory, I figured it out, my file was a .PHP and i had a .htaccess and i gues the JQUERY and that file did not sit well in other browsers. Am Not sure how to make it work without changing the file to an HTML file. It works for nw, but i will need PHP in my website, which will be a problem down the road because the ".htaccess" file is not working with the JQUERY. if you know of any solution to that, your help will be appreciated

Comment: Hmm, that is strange that JQ is not working with your php. Check out the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347966/php-jquery-how-to-use-these-two-together-please-see-my-example

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a # in front of product - e.g:

this:

```
<div>
    <a href="#products_content"> <span id="product_select"> PRODUCTS </span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have associated controller methods in your C# file (or controller if MVC). If so, could you post these please?

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code tries to scroll to #product_content but your HTML mentions products_content. Have you tried adding the missing hash sign and s?